# How to print/detect a null value in C

Tags: c

I have the following function where I'm trying to pass a `NULL` to emulate an "optional" parameter:

```
char * slice2(const char * str, const unsigned int * start, const unsigned int * end) {

    size_t string_len = strlen(str);

    printf("Start: %d | End: %d\n", *start, *end);

    if (*start == NULL) inferred_start = 0;
    if (*end == NULL) inferred_end = string_len;

    // more code and such
}
```

And called as:

```
unsigned int start = 6;
printf("'%s' ==> %s\n", "String", slice2("String", &start, NULL));
```

What would be the proper way to do the above?

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement.  This will likely trigger an illegal instruction error if it even compiles.

Comment: `char * slice2(const char * str, const size_t * start, const size_t * end) {
    size_t begin = (start == NULL ? 0 : *start);
    return (end == NULL ? strdup(str + begin) : strndup(str + begin, *end - begin));
}` https://godbolt.org/z/DUINJi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` is a pointer to an `unsigned int`, so `*start` is an `unsigned int`, an integer.

Your test `if (*start == NULL)` is trying to compare an integer value to a null pointer constant.

Unfortunately, it could compile without error, because `NULL` can legally be defined simply as `0`. But to test whether `start` is a null pointer, use

```
if (start == NULL) ...
```

and likewise for `end`.

Also, this line:

```
printf("Start: %d | End: %d\n", *start, *end);
```

should be executed only *after* you've confirmed that neither `start` nor `end` is a null pointer.

Comment: thanks for this. It's very helpful for understanding what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Additionally, why can't I do something like `if (end == NULL) *end = string_len;` ? That will raise a Segmentation Fault (if I don't declare it a constant to start with).

Comment: @Shared If `end` is NULL then `*end` tries to dereference a NULL pointer. Do you understand why that is a problem?

Comment: @Blastfurnace -- I see, so in that case, I'd want to do something like -- `inferred_end = (end != NULL) ? *end : string_len;`, right?